# How to calculate the total conversion time of DAC?

Tags: dac

In the system shown below, the decoder conversion time is 100 ns, and the amplifier has unity gain bandwidth of 10 kHz. DC gain of 1000.

What is the total conversion time of the system?

The closed loop pole is:

w = w<sub>0</sub>(1 + 1000 × 1) = 1001 × 10000 = 10010000 = 10.1 MHz

So the tau of the amplifier is

Tau = 1/(2 × π × w) = 1.57 × 10<sup>-8</sup>.

So the total time is the sum of Tau and 100 ns?

[image]

Comment: The amplifier is configured as unity gain, not 1000 : if that's the open loop gain, say so. And if that's an 8 to 3 decoder, then this is not a DAC. What drives the decoder's inputs?  Then, output settling time will be a function of the accuracy required which is unspecified. This is too much of a mess to answer.

Comment: The total time for *which change*?  You could consider the worst case, maximum voltage change and calculate when the output voltage will be closer to the correct output than the output of any other code...  Eg 0->255 and determine when the voltage is closer to what it should be for 255 than 254.